# How to set priorities and annotations on Jersey filters using JDK 1.8

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, servlet-filters

JDK 1.7 had `javax.annotation.Priority` annotation that helped in specifying the order in which filters should execute. It appears Priority class is no longer available in JDK1.8 - any idea how to set Filter ordering on Jersey? I am on JDK1.8 and Jersey. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standard Java annotation. It's in the [`javax.annotation-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api) jar. If you're using Maven or Gradle, it should already be pulled in by Jersey.